# Sylius Product Bundle as dependency

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I have an existing Symfony2 project which I'm attempting to install and use certain bundles from the Sylius project as dependencies. Here is my problem, I've added the SyliusProductBundle and all of its dependencies; however, when I attempt to update my database schema with:

app/console doctrine:scheme:update --force

I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                     
Class 'Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Model\ProductInterface' does not exist
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, although it seems to be some sort of namespacing issue?

I have the following configuration:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        src.user:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            templates: App:User
            classes:
                model: SRC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User

sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            model: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Product
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\ProductController
            repository: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
            form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ProductType
```

Comment: Please add more information to the question. What **version** of SyliusBundle are you using ( what's the require-entry in composer.json) ? Can you confirm the bundle has been downloaded correctly to the vendor-folder? does the file containing `ProductInterface` actually exist? **Where** is the exception thrown? Did you try running `composer dump-autoload -o` to create a new autoloader?

Comment: Thanks for the response! But umpirsky nailed it. But to answer your question I'm on the 1.0 dev. And the interface did exist. The exception didn't include a stacktrace so I couldn't find where it was being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please register the bundle before DoctrineBundle. This is important as we use listeners which have to be processed first.